# How do I convert an object that contains and arraylist of other objects into JSON for sending to an API - Android

Tags: android, json, object, arraylist

Imagine I have an object - ChildObject.  ChildObject has 3 properties.  Id, Name, Age.

I also have another object - ParentObject.  ParentObject also has 3 properties. Id, Date but the 3rd is ArrayList of ChildObjects Family.

How would I go about converting this into a JSONObject to be able to send it over to a RESTfull WebAPI service.

So far I have failed to find anything that works, and I'm struggling to wrap my head around the problem.

To make it more of a challenge I cant use 3rd party extentions (eg gson etc).

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Adding Objects to see if they make it any clearer**
ParentObject

```js
public class JobMovementRequestDto {

    public String Id_Employee;
    public String ActionDate;
    public String Id_Terminal;
    public String Id_Device;
    public ArrayList<JobActivityRequestDto> FromJobs;
    public ArrayList<JobActivityRequestDto> ToJobs;

    public JobMovementRequestDto(){

    }

    public JobMovementRequestDto(String idEmployee, String activityDate, String idTerminal, String idDevice, ArrayList<JobActivityRequestDto> fromItems, ArrayList<JobActivityRequestDto> toItems){

        this.Id_Employee = idEmployee;
        this.ActionDate = activityDate;
        this.Id_Terminal = idTerminal;
        this.Id_Device = idDevice;
        this.FromJobs = fromItems;
        this.ToJobs = toItems;
    }

    public String getIdEmployee() {return this.Id_Employee;}

    public String getActivityDate() {return this.ActionDate;}

    public String getIdTerminal() {return this.Id_Terminal;}

    public String getIdDevice() {return this.Id_Device;}

    public ArrayList<JobActivityRequestDto> getFromList() {return this.FromJobs;}

    public ArrayList<JobActivityRequestDto> getToLIst() { return this.ToJobs;}
```

ChildObject

```js
public class JobActivityRequestDto {

    public String Id_Job;
    public String Id_Batch;
    public String Id_ActivityType;

    public JobActivityRequestDto()
    {

    }

    public JobActivityRequestDto(String idJob, String idBatch, String idActivityType)
    {
        this.Id_Job = idJob;
        this.Id_Batch = idBatch;
        this.Id_ActivityType = idActivityType;
    }

    public String getIdJob() { return this.Id_Job;}

    public String getIdBatch() {return this.Id_Batch;}

    public String getIdActivityType() {return this.Id_ActivityType;}

}
```

Comment: are you using any library for network operations ?

Comment: this sort of depends on what you are using to build your obj in the first place

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Everything is "out the box" java.  We have no 3rd party libraries for anything.  Our api calls work in every other case.  The problem occurs when we try to convert ParentObject ready for sending (ie we havent got to the actual send part yet)

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack - I have added the real objects to the question.  They are very normal and boring classes :)

Comment: Use `Gson` library, `Gson gson=new Gson()` and `gson.toJson(pass-your-element-here)`.It will give you `Json` `string`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and assistance.  It is greatly apprteciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JSONObject fromObject, toObject, parentObject;
    JSONArray fromArray, toArray;

    JobMovementRequestDto JMRD = new JobMovementRequestDto();
    try {
        parentObject = new JSONObject();
        parentObject.put("Id_Employee", JMRD.getIdEmployee());
        parentObject.put("ActionDate", JMRD.getActivityDate());
        parentObject.put("Id_Terminal", JMRD.getIdTerminal());
        parentObject.put("Id_Device", JMRD.getIdDevice());

        fromArray = new JSONArray();
        for(JobActivityRequestDto JARD : JMRD.getFromList()){
            //Loop your multiple childObjects and add it childArray
            fromObject = new JSONObject();
            fromObject.put("Id_Job",JARD.getIdJob());
            fromObject.put("Id_Batch",JARD.getIdBatch());
            fromObject.put("Id_ActivityType",JARD.getIdActivityType());
            fromArray.put(fromObject);
        }

        toArray = new JSONArray();
        for(JobActivityRequestDto JARD : JMRD.getToLIst()){
            //Loop your multiple childObjects and add it childArray
            toObject = new JSONObject();
            toObject.put("Id_Job",JARD.getIdJob());
            toObject.put("Id_Batch",JARD.getIdBatch());
            toObject.put("Id_ActivityType",JARD.getIdActivityType());
            toArray.put(toObject);
        }

        //Finally, Add childArray to ParentObject.
        parentObject.put("fromObjects",fromArray);
        parentObject.put("toObjects",toArray);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Create a JSON like this and You Can Send This to Your Server. I Hope This Is What You Want Right?

Comment: Thanks - this nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your complete solution, Please check.

```
public void makeJsonObject()
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject parentJsonObject = new JSONObject();

        parentJsonObject.put("Id", parentObject.getId());
        parentJsonObject.put("Id", parentObject.getDate());

        JSONArray childListArr = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < parentObject.ChildObjectsList().size(); i++)
        {
            ChildObject childObject = parentObject.ChildObjectsList().get(i);

            JSONObject childJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            childJsonObject.put("id", childObject.getId());
            childJsonObject.put("Name", childObject.getName());
            childJsonObject.put("Age", childObject.getAge());

            childListArr.put(childJsonObject);
        }

        parentJsonObject.put("childList", childListArr);


        Log.e(TAG, "parentJsonObject=="+parentJsonObject.toString(4));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i can only pick one answer - thanks for your help

Comment: NP man, doesn't matter to check the answer. If it helped you I will satisfy. :)